# Why cannot allow/deny specific software in ufw Linux?

Tags: networking, windows, iptables, firewall, ufw

Why cannot allow specific software (like Firefox) to use internet but deny other software (link Chrome) that are using same port in ufw? In windows there is the feature, why ufw don't have that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `apparmor` to deny network traffic for some application.
First you must install `apparmor` and `apparmor-utils` ..

```
sudo apt-get install apparmor*
```

After that you can generate profile to you application ...

```
sudo aa-genprof /usr/bin/google-chrome
```

Next step is to change `Networking` part in profile to:

```
sudo nano /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.chromium-browser

audit deny network,
audit deny network inet stream,
deny network inet6 stream,
deny @{PROC}/[0-9]*/net/if_inet6 r,
deny @{PROC}/[0-9]*/net/ipv6_route r,
deny capability net_raw,
```

Next, check config with apparmor_parser and reload config

```
sudo apparmor_parser -r /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.chromium-browser
```

Change mode from `complain` to `enforce` aka turn on `apparmor` for this app.

```
sudo aa-complain /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.chromium-browser
```

More manual you can find [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppArmor) and [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1008906) and [here](http://blog.bodhizazen.com/linux/apparmor-privoxy-profile/)

Second solution is more simple but is not completly what you want

Surfing on net I found [trickle](http://www.tuxradar.com/content/control-your-bandwidth-trickle). Fine and light tool for control bandwidth on application

Install them

```
  sudo apt-get install trickle
```

Usage is very simple

```
  trickle -d 1 firefox
```

this command will allow `firefox` to download at speed of 1 kb/s

Or you can add `trickle` to luncher

[image: trinckle_luncher]

Also you can create permanent control in `/etc/trickled.conf` per service. Not for bandwidth then for traffic priority

Comment: Is there any GUI for `apparmor` ?